# Method that returns either false or an array only tests as false or true

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods

I'm working on a method that return false or an Array.  When I call this array inside another method and try to assign it to a variable I'm expecting that the variable with hold either false or the returned Array.

What's happening is that when I assign the result of the method to the variable it's only resulting in true or false rather than false or an Array

I've used the pry method inside the method being called to determine what is going to be returned.  I've confirmed that an Array will be returned and then with an additional pry determined that the variable is only set true when an array is returned

```rb
WIN_COMBINATIONS = [
  [0,1,2],
  [3,4,5],
  [6,7,8],
  [0,3,6],
  [1,4,7],
  [2,5,8],
  [0,4,8],
  [2,4,6]
  ]

def won?(board)
  #for the purpose of this study, winner(board) returns nil or "X" or "O"
  result = winner(board)
  if result == nil 
    #if the result of winner is null, return false
    return false  
  end
  #return the array at location 0
  return WIN_COMBINATIONS[0]
end

def play(board)
  #i'm attempting to assign the return of the won? method to result
  result = won?(board)
  #when result is evaluated, when an array is being returned, result becomes true or false,
  #rather than what I'd expect as false or an array
end
```

Comment: The code is extremely not idiomatic ruby, but it works (`result` would get assigned to an array.) There is an induced issue somewhere else. Please post all the code (including how do you check it’s an array.)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin As I'm a newb to ruby I'm intrigued by your statement 'extremely not idiomatic'.  Now's the time for me to learn how it should be written :) To check my code I used a binding.pry before the return statement in won? and asked what WIN_COMBINATIONS[0] was.  Another binding.pry was placed after the result assignment in the method play, result was checked there

Comment: It seems like the code should work, but without knowing what `#winner` is doing, I can't tell. BTW you can shorten the method and just return:

`winner(board).nil? ? false : WIN_COMBINATIONS.first`

Comment: @HP_hovercraft #winner returns nil, "X" or "O"  .  Appreciate the coding tip ;)

Comment: Maybe the `#winner` method isn't return nil on any state. You can make a unit test for it to ensure that it is doing that?

Comment: Remember that in Ruby `return` is implied, the last element in the method is what gets returned. You only need to use an explicit `return` statement if you're exiting early. Additionally only `false` and `nil` are logically false in Ruby, so you can write `return false unless result` or even `result && WIN_COMBINATIONS[0]`

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to stick at the convention that a method ending with a question mark should return `true` or `false`, that would definitely be more idiomatic ruby.

In your example could be something like

```
def won?(board)
  !!winner(board)
end
```

then inside the method `play`

```
def play(board)
  result = won?(board) ? WIN_COMBINATIONS[0] : false
  # or a shorter one line 
  # result = won?(board) && WIN_COMBINATIONS[0]
end
```